# JavaScript to PHP variables

Tags: javascript

I have a html Code with javascript. i need to pass the values captured on this page to a php which inturn calls a stored procedure in mySql. I am unable to pass the variables. Here is snippet.

```
 <TABLE border="0" width = "700" cellspacing ="15 pixles"  >
                        <TR>
                          <TH>Agent ID
                          <TD><input type="text" size="40" name="agentid" id ="agentid">
                       <TR>

                       <TH>Name
                          <TD><input type="text" size="40" name="sendername" id="sendername" >
                       <TR>
                          <TH>Address Line 1
                          <TD><input type="text" size="40" name="senderaddress1" id ="senderaddress1">
                    </TABLE>
```

## javascript:

```html
    <ul class="tab-links" style="margin-left: 150px; width: 550px;" >
                           <li class="current_page_item"><a href="#tab3">Previous</a></li>
                           <li id="Summary" ><a href="javascript:submitorder();">PRINT Summary</a></li>
        
         <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript">

          function submitorder() { 
          
          var p_in_agent_id  = document.getElementById("agentid").innerText;
          var e = document.getElementById("dropoffpoint");
          var p_in_rate_city = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
          
          
          var p_in_sendername  = document.getElementById("sendername").value;        
          var p_in_senderaddress1  = document.getElementById("senderaddress1").value;
            
$.post('orderentry.php', function(data) { 
     window.alert ("Iam 2");
            $('div#layer_1').html(data);
            });
            //}
          };
         </script>
```

## THE PHP Sample

```
<?php  
include("connect.php"); 


try {

    $ref_awb = 0;
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=mydatabase", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    //$sql = "GetPrice(?, ?)";
    $sql = "Call proc_order_insert (:input1,:input2,:input3,:input4,:input5,:input6,:input7,:input8,:input9,:input10,:input11,:input12,:input13,:input14,:input15,:input16,:input17,:input18,:input19,:input20,:input21,:input22,:input23,:input24,:input25,:input26,:input27,:input28,:input29,:input30,:input31,:input32,:input33,:input34,:input35,:input36,:input37,:input38,:input39,:input40,:input41,:input42,:input43,:input44,:input45,:input46,:input47,:input48, @output_awb)";


    $p_in_agent_id = localStorage.getItem("p_in_agent_id");
    echo (p_in_agentid);
    $p_in_sendername = p_in_sendername;
```

### etc etc etc

The parameters are not getting passed to php..

Comment: According to your code you are sending the `data` object to the page `orderentry.php`. I cannot see where you define `data`?

Comment: ... you do realize that in HTML, tags are closed like `</TAG>`? `<TAG>` is opening....

Comment: i am assigning them to variables var in the html and calling the orderentry.php not sure how the data will be passed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Ajax to execute the script php and passing the data.
So your javascript can be like this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function submitorder() { 

    var p_in_agent_id  = document.getElementById("agentid").innerText;
    var e = document.getElementById("dropoffpoint");
    var p_in_rate_city = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;


    var p_in_sendername  = document.getElementById("sendername").value;                             
    var p_in_senderaddress1  = document.getElementById("senderaddress1").value;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "orderentry.php",
        data: {var_in_agent_id : p_in_agent_id, var_in_sendername : p_in_sendername},
        dataType: "text",
        success: function (rslt) {
            //success
        }
    });
};
</script>
```

And in the script php you can do like this code:

```
$ref_awb = 0;
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=mydatabase", $username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
//$sql = "GetPrice(?, ?)";
$sql = "Call proc_order_insert (:input1,:input2,:input3,:input4,:input5,:input6,:input7,:input8,:input9,:input10,:input11,:input12,:input13,:input14,:input15,:input16,:input17,:input18,:input19,:input20,:input21,:input22,:input23,:input24,:input25,:input26,:input27,:input28,:input29,:input30,:input31,:input32,:input33,:input34,:input35,:input36,:input37,:input38,:input39,:input40,:input41,:input42,:input43,:input44,:input45,:input46,:input47,:input48, @output_awb)";


$p_in_agent_id = $_POST["var_in_agent_id"];
echo ($p_in_agent_id);
$p_in_sendername = $_POST["var_in_sendername"];
...
```

you can inspect the item and ensure that parameters are sent in the request POST in AJAX like this capture
[image]

If you have one parameter to send to the html page, you can do :

```
$ref_awb = 0;
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=mydatabase", $username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
//$sql = "GetPrice(?, ?)";
$sql = "Call proc_order_insert (:input1,:input2,:input3,:input4,:input5,:input6,:input7,:input8,:input9,:input10,:input11,:input12,:input13,:input14,:input15,:input16,:input17,:input18,:input19,:input20,:input21,:input22,:input23,:input24,:input25,:input26,:input27,:input28,:input29,:input30,:input31,:input32,:input33,:input34,:input35,:input36,:input37,:input38,:input39,:input40,:input41,:input42,:input43,:input44,:input45,:input46,:input47,:input48, @output_awb)";


$p_in_agent_id = $_POST["var_in_agent_id"];
$p_in_sendername = $_POST["var_in_sendername"];
echo $output_awb;
```

And in the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function submitorder() { 

        var p_in_agent_id  = document.getElementById("agentid").innerText;
        var e = document.getElementById("dropoffpoint");
        var p_in_rate_city = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;


        var p_in_sendername  = document.getElementById("sendername").value;                             
        var p_in_senderaddress1  = document.getElementById("senderaddress1").value;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "orderentry.php",
            data: {var_in_agent_id : p_in_agent_id, var_in_sendername : p_in_sendername},
            dataType: "text",
            success: function (rslt) {
                $('div#layer_1').html(rslt);
            }
        });
    };
    </script>
```

If ya have many parameters to send to the html page you shoulld do:

```
$ref_awb = 0;
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=mydatabase", $username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
//$sql = "GetPrice(?, ?)";
$sql = "Call proc_order_insert (:input1,:input2,:input3,:input4,:input5,:input6,:input7,:input8,:input9,:input10,:input11,:input12,:input13,:input14,:input15,:input16,:input17,:input18,:input19,:input20,:input21,:input22,:input23,:input24,:input25,:input26,:input27,:input28,:input29,:input30,:input31,:input32,:input33,:input34,:input35,:input36,:input37,:input38,:input39,:input40,:input41,:input42,:input43,:input44,:input45,:input46,:input47,:input48, @output_awb)";


$p_in_agent_id = $_POST["var_in_agent_id"];
$p_in_sendername = $_POST["var_in_sendername"];
$output = array(
    "p_in_agent_id" => $p_in_agent_id,
    "output_awb" => $output_awb
);
echo json_encode($output);
```

And in the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function submitorder() { 

        var p_in_agent_id  = document.getElementById("agentid").innerText;
        var e = document.getElementById("dropoffpoint");
        var p_in_rate_city = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;


        var p_in_sendername  = document.getElementById("sendername").value;                             
        var p_in_senderaddress1  = document.getElementById("senderaddress1").value;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "orderentry.php",
            data: {var_in_agent_id : p_in_agent_id, var_in_sendername : p_in_sendername},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (rslt) {
                var result = jQuery.parseJSON(rslt.trim());
                $('div#layer_1').html(result.p_in_agent_id);
                $('div#layer_2').html(result.output_awb);
            }
        });
    };
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks Aminesrine. But I am getting this error :Notice: Undefined index: var_in_agent_id in C:\wamp\www\HVFinal\orderentry.ph

Comment: This error means that parameters not sended to the script php, I edited my answers.

Comment: Thanks , i have never used AJAX before. The issue what I see is I am not able to populate the result in the same page. I added this bit of code:


             success: function (rslt) {
              //success
              layer_1.html(html);
             },
             error:function (jqXHR, status, err){
              //Fail
              layer_1.html(html);
             }

But there is some error which i am not able to visualise at all

In the previous code, $('div#layer_1').html(data); would display the data in same html..

Comment: ya have results from the scipt php to dispaly in the html page?

Comment: Thanks this worked. However, What I want is to return the output. Where I have 2 issues:
1.  the stored procedure returns a confirmation number. I am confused with the way it has to be handled. if you look at the last parameter of the SQL @output_awb, how should I pass this parameter or get value for this parameter?
2. How can i display this value from the calling html page on specific div?

Comment: sorry, i mstill a newbie here. I am able to process all these. Now i need to read parameter from URL.
http://localhost/v1/pan.html?id=%20%20{%22pan_ref_id%22:%22HVP000037%22}
I have created a function:
var urlParams;
   function get_parameters(){

var url = location.search.substr(location.search.indexOf("?")+1);
window.alert (url);

but how can i get only the last bit i.e hvp000037 from the above url

Comment: You can open a new question

Comment: here you go http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38945235/unable-to-read-key-value-pair-of-json-encode-in-javascript