# Unable to read key value pair of Json_encode in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am having issues with reading Json_encode response in a java script.

The PHP file reads values from database and sends the results as Json_encode array to html.

```
<?php  
 include("connect.php"); 
 try {

    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=mydb", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "Call print_awb (@output1,@output2,:input_awb_ref_id)";
    if (isset($_POST)) {
        $p_in_awb_ref_id =reset($_POST["var_p_in_awb_ref_id"]);
    }
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);               
    $stmt->bindParam(':input_awb_ref_id',$p_in_awb_ref_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    $out_awb_ref_id  = $conn->query("SELECT @output1")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
    $out_agent_id  = $conn->query("SELECT @output2")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

    $output = array(            
        "out_awb_ref_id" => $out_awb_ref_id,
        "out_agent_id" => $out_agent_id,
    );
    echo json_encode($output);
    $stmt->closeCursor(); 
}   
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

## The HTML CODE

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function get_parameters(){

            var quote = ABCD1234;
            quote.toString();
            window.alert(quote);
            $.ajax({
                type:  "POST",
                url: "printawb.php",
                data: {var_p_in_awb_ref_id:quote},
                dataType: "text",
                success: function (result) {

                    alert(result);
                    var a = result.out_awb_ref_id;
                    alert (a);
                    alert(result['out_awb_ref_id']);
                    alert(result['out_agent_id'])
                },
                error:function (jqXHR, status, err){
                    //Fail
                    layer_1.html(html);
                }

            });
            return vars;

        };
</script>
```

## The response I have is

> HVP000062
>
> {"out_awb_ref_id":{"@output1":"MIR"},"out_agent_id":{"@output2":"rtPreston"}}
>   undefined
>   undefined

***All Need is the values in the 2nd line of the result ie. "MIR" and "rtPreston"***

I have tried couple of things:
 1. changed the calling function type as 'JSON' but the response was 'Object' without values
 2. Tried converting to jsonString 
3. tried reading values using JSON.parse(jsonString);
4. result['out_ref_awb_id']

None of them work. Can someone help me how I can get values of these? I can then use them to populate on a html page.

Many thanks

Comment: Try to get rid of that undefined parameters within the json string.
https://jsfiddle.net/2tsewfvj/ works just fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this as a first line in the HEAD section of your HTML template

```
<meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
```

Then try this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function get_parameters(){

        var quote = ABCD1234;
        quote.toString();
        window.alert(quote);
        $.ajax({
            type:  "POST",
            url: "printawb.php",
            data: {var_p_in_awb_ref_id:quote},
            dataType: "text",
            success: function (result) {

                var data = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
                var param1 = data.out_agent_id;
                var param2 = data.out_awb_ref_id;
                alert(param1["@output2"]);
                alert(param2["@output1"])
            },
            error:function (jqXHR, status, err){
                //Fail
                layer_1.html(html);
            }
        });
        return vars;

    };
</script>
```

Comment: #Errors#

1. The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared....

2. SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data
get_parameters/<.success()
 awb.html:24
jQuery.Callbacks/fire()
 jquery-3.1.0.js:3243
jQuery.Callbacks/self.fireWith()
 jquery-3.1.0.js:3373
done()
 jquery-3.1.0.js:9098
.send/callback/<()
 jquery-3.1.0.js:9340

Comment: For the first error: I edited my answer. For the second error: you are sure that you used "dataType : 'json'," in the ajax call?

Comment: I hAve fixed HTML encoding error.  It is the syntax error which still needs your inputs. I added an alert on result before the JSON Parse, the result is coming as [object Object],[object Object] but when I use dataType as Text, the response is    [{"@output1":"ABC"},{"@output2":"rtcheck"}]


**bold**Is there any problem with the php file? @aminesrine**bold**

Comment: Try using function "jQuery.parseJSON" in place the function "JSON.parse" with dataType: "text"